# setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays

So I'm not the best at python but I need to create this program for one of my courses and I keep getting this error.

Basically I have `w_array = linspace(0.6, 1.1, 11)`, then I have `zq = array([1, 1, w_array, 1])`

and it comes up with the error message:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

the basic function of the code is to take a bezier spline aerofoil, with control points and weights, run the data in xfoil and print cd and cl values, but this addition is to show a graph of the range of cd for a certain control point.

hope it makes sense, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the error? Would be nice to know

Comment: Word of warning: wanting an array to be made up of two integers, and then an array of floats, and then another integer, is a strange thing to want.  You may have taken a wrong turn.

Comment: the error was 'setting an array element with a sequence' and @dsm thats how the uni wanted us to go about the code,considering i have such little knowledge in python i have no clue!

Comment: @user3310983: well, I can't speak to what your university requested, but that's not something you'd ordinarily do in numpy.  If you do that, say using `dtype=object`, standard numpy vector arithmetic won't work any more.  But under the circumstances I'd do whatever the people grading you say to. :^)

Comment: this is what they wanted 'A function
parameter
sweep(w
array,cl,file
path,xfoil
path)
which
is the same as
run
xfoil
wcl()
, but where
w
array
is an array of weights
for the control point at
[0.4, 0.2]
. The function should return the cor-
responding array of
C
D
values.
Example:
>>>
w
array = linspace (0.6 , 1.2 , 11)
>>>
print parameter
sweep ( w
array , 0.843 , file
path , xfoil
path )
[ 0.00744 0.00697 0.00669 0.00655 0.0065 0.00681 0.00706
0.00721
0.00733 0.00746 0.00759]'

Answer (score 2):

If you want `zq` be an array containing both ints and lists, use parameter `dtype`:

```
In [300]: zq = array([1, 1, w_array, 1], dtype=object)

In [301]: zq
Out[301]: 
array([1, 1,
       array([ 0.6 ,  0.65,  0.7 ,  0.75,  0.8 ,  0.85,  0.9 ,  0.95,  1.  ,
        1.05,  1.1 ]),
       1], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this your intended result?

```
In [2]:
numpy.hstack((1,1,numpy.linspace(0.6,1.1,11),1))
Out[2]:
array([ 1.  ,  1.  ,  0.6 ,  0.65,  0.7 ,  0.75,  0.8 ,  0.85,  0.9 ,
        0.95,  1.  ,  1.05,  1.1, 1. ])
```

You probably want the resulting `array` to have `float64` `dtypes` rather than `object`, a mixed bag of `dtypes`, as @DSM pointed out.

Comment: when i use it it gives me an error '
TypeError: hstack() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
' but yes thats essentially what i want as the result

Comment: make sure you have the right number of '(' and ')'. :-)

Comment: ok i'll have a quick look, sorry about the questions, i'm just struggling with getting to grips with python haha

Comment: its still coming up with errors, im not entirely sure my code is correct is correct aha

Comment: Check the doc out http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html. You should be fine if you correctly put all the data in a `tuple`.